# Getting invalid value for Integer() in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following table in my Rails app that contains Permissions:

```
id: INTEGER, name: TEXT, controller: TEXT, action: TEXT, description: TEXT, created_at: TEXT, updated_at: TEXT
```

And I want to write or update to it all of the controller actions in my application so that they can be used against roles/users in `CanCanCan`.

This is achieved by hitting the `build` method in my `PermissionsController`

```
def build
  write_permission("all", "manage", "Everything", "All operations", true)
  ApplicationController.subclasses.each do |controller|
    if controller.respond_to?(:permission)
      controller_class, description = controller.permission
      write_permission(controller_class, "manage", description, "All operations")
      controller.action_methods.each do |action|
        if action.to_s.index("_callback").nil?
          action_desc, cancan_action = eval_cancan_action(action)
          write_permission(controller_class, cancan_action, description, action_desc)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So the idea is that it loops through all the controllers and actions and then call calls `write_permission` to add or update the DB.

```
protected

  def eval_cancan_action(action)
    case action.to_s
      when "index", "show", "search"
        cancan_action = "read"
        action_desc = I18n.t :read
      when "create", "new"
        cancan_action = "create"
        action_desc = I18n.t :create
      when "edit", "update"
        cancan_action = "update"
        action_desc = I18n.t :edit
      when "delete", "destroy"
        cancan_action = "delete"
        action_desc = I18n.t :delete
      else
        cancan_action = action.to_s
        action_desc = "Other: " << cancan_action
    end
    return action_desc, cancan_action
  end

  def write_permission(controller, cancan_action, name, description, force_id_1 = false)
    permission = Permission.first(:conditions => ["controller = ? and action = ?", controller, cancan_action])
    if not permission
      permission = Permission.new
      permission.id = 1 if force_id_1
      permission.controller =  controller
      permission.action = cancan_action
      permission.name = name
      permission.description = description
      permission.save
    else
      permission.name = name
      permission.description = description
      permission.save
    end
  end
```

However I get this error:

```
invalid value for Integer(): "{:conditions=>[\"controller = ? and action = ?\""
```

I can't understand what the issue is, as the only INTEGER is the id.

But we're not finding the first Permission using id...

Comment: If you're getting this error and it's for a String column/attribute of a model, check your version of the `psych` gem (https://github.com/ruby/psych/) and try updating it. I had to update from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0 in order for this issue to be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is with the way you are using the `first` method on `Permission`. See the documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first

You could write it this way instead:

`Permission.where(controller: controller, action: cancan_action).first`

Comment: I think `Permission.find_by(controller: controller, action: cancan_action)` will produce the same result.